# Uniform convergence of bounded series

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

Is it true that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$ 
$$\bigg\vert\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \lambda (1-\lambda)^n a_n - \sum_{n=0}^{N} \lambda (1-\lambda)^n a_n\bigg\vert< \epsilon.$$

Comment: The question reduces to whether there is an $N$ such that $$\sum_{n = N+1}^{\infty} \lambda(1-\lambda)^n < \epsilon.$$ Is $\lambda$ fixed, or should that hold for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$?

Comment: For a fixed $\lambda$, it is just a geometric series.